# asp mvc how to serve image/file/video out of my root folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Backend on Asp.Net MVC4 witch in a database stores a "filename" y it "Path". Example:

```
FileName        Path
AAAA           V:\Clientes\FileName1.pdf
BBBB           V:\Clientes\FileName2.pdf
DDDD           V:\Clientes\FileName3.pdf
CCCC           V:\Clientes\FileName4.pdf
```

The fact is that I´m going to consume this response (JSON) from a cordova application, and I need theese files to be served with my aplication for example with a url like this:

```
www.myawesomeapp.com/files/FileName1.pdf
```

How to achieve this? They don´t want to upload anything, the only want to say to the backend where in the server ( mapped drive ) are stored the files, nothing more, but this is not valid in order to open this files on a client side.

Any help or clue? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in this scenario, you would create a controller and set of action methods to deliver the files to the user.  This allows you to keep control over the URL formatting and path and allows you to perform security and authorization checks on the user requesting the file (if they are not public).

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{
     //I guess you would want to lookup by filename?
     public FileResult Index(string filename ){
            var fileToReturn = new FileStream("full path to file", FileMode.Open);
            return File(fileToReturn, "content-disposition", "fileName.extension");
     }
}
```

The URL you have used as an example should now return the FileName1.pdf. Actually, based on your "table" up top, the url might be something along the lines of `http://www.myawesomeapp.com/Files/AAAA`. There is some work inside of this method you will still need to do to translate the filename parameter (or an id or however you look up your files) into what actual file you should be retrieving.

Comment: thx! it works on visual studio... it downloads the file ;) now I´m going to work on the cordova part ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can just map the network location as a virtual directory in IIS under the site that's bound to this domain.